# Lightning: How to make a quick action that updates a status on a record

Tags: lightning, field-update, quickaction

I'm really at a loss. I think it should be dead-easy to create a button that updates a status, but I can't work it out. 
On a custom record page I want a Quick Action button. When the user presses that button the status (a field on the record) needs to be set to a certain value.

The closest I got was creating a custom component and call that component from the Quick Button. But annoyingly this comes up with a popup (in which the componant normally would show) whilst my component's Init method updates the status as I want. This works, but is not what I want.
The second aproach would be to use a flow URL in a button, but unfortunately you can't use regular buttons in Lightning either :(

Now I've also been looking at workflows and other stuff, so I'm not opposed to a 'non-coding' approach. I just don't know how to do it...
Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no real solution for my usecase at the moment. 
Closing.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options that i can think of

1.Create a custom lightning component for Detail Page and a custom code to update record

The lightning component will be a simple button with a server call to update record

2.Create an action that has a VF page and onload the page would update the record .Please be aware that onload do not update or do a DML as that would create a security threat Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery)

So easiest approach would be to build a simple lightning component and drop on record detail page .

Comment: As I mention in my question, the Lightning Component option works, but serves a popup, and I would like to avoid that.
Your 2nd option doesn't work on for Lighting, and as you say yourself wouldn't allow a DML.

Comment: @Marco my first option is to use lightning component on detail page and avoid quick action .For second dml is allowed on action attribute but it has security threat

Comment: Thanks. Using a component on the detail page is my starting point, but I thought it to be more elegant to use the quick buttons. But apparently it's not possible to trigger any update without using a form. It just seemed too obvious so I thought I missed something. 
I'll stick with my button component then.